# Socket.Select returns error "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

When calling Socket.Select with lists that are verified to contain only Socket objects, I sometimes receive the error `An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`. I can't find a pattern for occurrence.

```
Socket.Select(readList, writeList, null, timeOut > 0 ? timeOut : 0);
```

Comment: Definitely environmental, chase the KB articles.

Comment: This is the coolest error I've seen this month. It takes a lot of humility for a computer to admit it just doesn't know what's going on.

Comment: i just solved this problem "in my case" by running the program with administrator rights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the sockets were closed. That's a really dumb error for .NET to be generating though just because of a closed socket.

Comment: Isn't this a security problem? The socket class seemingly did native calls on a closed handle! That is a handle recycling attack.

Comment: I got this "all of a sudden" with an app that often fails to connect because I've lost contact with the handheld. I re"seat" the handheld in its cradle, it is "seen" again by the desktop, and all is well - except for this time, when I got this "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket" error.

Comment: Closing the project and VS 2008 and reopening made it go away. Dad-burned varmints! I mean gremlins!

Answer (score 2):

I did a search on MSDN and got a couple of hits. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817571) & [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318584)

However, I haven't develop anything in WinSock but on Unix the way `Select` is implemented requires resetting the `fd_set` everytime `Select` returns. Maybe the same applies to WinSock implementation of Select also. If this is the case, your `readList, writeList` may have got *corrupted* after `Select` returned leading to the error you mentioned. Just a thought.

Comment: Good thoughts, but we do reinitialize the lists before calling `Select` each time. Thanks though.

Comment: oh..and the MSDN links also don't point to a kind of situation you might be having?

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue when my host machine firewall is on.
i can't add disable my firewall due to my company rules.
So i have added inbound rules in my host machine for communication after that it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Restart MYSQL Service may help you..

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SQL Server.