# How to eradicate the error An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket?

Tags: python, debugging

Whenever I seem to run [this](https://github.com/vaibhavsingh2/C200_TeacherReference) and open client.py on cmd it throws me a error

> Connected with the server...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\J****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\c-200\client.py", line 16, in 
> read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list,[],[])
> OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

How can I remove this error? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15210178) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3188392) but it didn't help out. When I did more research I found out

> Not a bug as EventInjector has never worked on windows.

However I didn't use EventInjector so I feel this is not the error. Is the error because of this only? Is it because of firewall? Is it because I have done some typo mistakes in code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The file in GitHub and the error message are unrelated. You are likely **not** running the expected script...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I wrote the code then went with the help of cmd to that location and first ran py server.py it ran fine however then i wrote py client.py in different cmd but with correct address at that time it showed this error. Does that code for you?

Comment: Control in the cmd window that you use to start the client that the `client.py` file is the correct one. The content of line 16 is not what is on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you change the code it does not automatically update your computer. Just change the code and restart your computer and it starts working